# Write intermediate Amazon EMR task output to S3

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I am running an EMR job that outputs several thousand gigabytes of data. Each map task outputs 10s of gigabytes of data, as far as I can tell these intermediate outputs are stored on disk on the machine running the map task. Thus, after the same machine has processed several map tasks it runs out of space on disk to store the intermediate results of these map tasks. I know how to store the final results (after the reducer is run) on S3, but is there a way to have the intermediate outputs (the results of the mapper) also stored on S3?

Unfortunately, just allocating more machines (or machines with more memory) is not a practical solution since I will be running the same job on several hundred terabytes of data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this issue, I was not able to find a way to use S3 to store the intermediate results of a map/reduce task. However, I was able to bypass the problem by upgrading to EMR 4.x and then attach EBS volumes to the cluster instances, as detailed here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-storage-ebs.html.